# What is the most efficient way to convert an array of objects to an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to convert an array of objects to a single object and the array I have is similar to the following;

```js
const array = [{id: '1', name: 'First'}, {id: '2', name: 'Second'}];
```

Expected output:

```
{'first': 1, 'second': 2}
```

Additionally, I want to change the casing of all values to lower case. Can assume that there are no spaces in between for the values for names. And all the ids are numbers.

Performance-wise, is there a better approach than this?

```js
const array = [{id: '1', name: 'First'}, {id: '2', name: 'Second'}];
console.log(array);
const result = array.reduce((accumulator, value) => {return {...accumulator, [value.name.toLowerCase()]: Number(value.id)}}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `for ... of` (or similar) will likely be most performant as it has no overhead of function calls. For example:

```js
const array = [
  {id: '1', name: 'First'},
  {id: '2', name: 'Second'}
];

let result = {};

for (o of array) {
  result[o.name.toLowerCase()] = parseInt(o.id);
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using a standard loop (for or while) would be the most efficient performance wise since it doesn't come with any additional stuff like map,reduce,sort do.

Answer (score 0):

You could create entries and generate an object from it.

```js
const
    array = [{ id: '1', name: 'First' }, { id: '2', name: 'Second' }],
    object = Object.fromEntries(array.map(({ id, name }) => [name.toLowerCase(), +id]));

console.log(object);
```

Comment: Can you explain why it is better than using a reducer, please?

Comment: it is just a compact approachwithout creating objects over an over.